Advanced cross filter from brush in deneb using vega
Here's a deneb line chart on the left and a table visual on the right in power bi.  The n values are mapped to the x-axis, the m values are mapped to the y-axis.  It is dummy data.

The chart can be brushed with the mouse events.

How can the brushed area filter the table on the right using advanced cross filtering?
Here is my attempt (with the full code at the bottom).  The idea is that when the mouseup event occurs, it applies the filter from the brush if it exists, otherwise clears the filter.
    // cross filter start ------------------------------------------
    {
      "name": "pbiCrossFilterSelection",
      "value": [],
      "on": [
        // when mark is brushed apply cross filter
        {
          "events": {
            "type": "mouseup"
          },
          "update": "main_brush ? pbiCrossFilterApply(event, \"datum['n'] > main_brush[0] & datum['n'] < main_brush[1]\" ) : pbiCrossFilterClear()"
        }
      ]
    }
    // cross filter end ------------------------------------------

I've found that if the event type is a click, it works however the brushed area gets unbrushed, so I'm hoping to get it working with mouseup.
I've been using this for guidance.  Here's the attempt:
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "dataset"
    }
  ],
  "width": 200,
  "height": 200,
  // brush signals
  "signals": [
    // brush
    {
      "name": "brush",
      "value": 0,
      "on": [
        {
          "events": "@main:pointerdown",
          "update": "[x(), x()]"
        },
        {
          "events": "[@main:pointerdown, window:pointerup] > window:pointermove!",
          "update": "[brush[0], clamp(round(x()-brush[0])+brush[0], 0, width)]"
        },
        {
          "events": {
            "signal": "delta"
          },
          "update": "clampRange([anchor[0] + delta, anchor[1] + delta], 0, width)"
        }
      ]
    },
    // anchor
    {
      "name": "anchor",
      "value": null,
      "on": [
        {
          "events": "@brush:pointerdown",
          "update": "slice(brush)"
        }
      ]
    },
    // xdown
    {
      "name": "xdown",
      "value": 0,
      "on": [
        {
          "events": "@brush:pointerdown",
          "update": "x()"
        }
      ]
    },
    // delta
    {
      "name": "delta",
      "value": 0,
      "on": [
        {
          "events": "[@brush:pointerdown, window:pointerup] > window:pointermove!",
          "update": "x() - xdown"
        }
      ]
    },
    // main_brush
    {
      "name": "main_brush",
      "on": [
        {
          "events": {
            "signal": "brush"
          },
          "update": "span(brush) ? invert('x_scale', brush) : null"
        }
      ]
    },
    // cross filter start ------------------------------------------
    {
      "name": "pbiCrossFilterSelection",
      "value": [],
      "on": [
        // when mark is brushed apply cross filter
        {
          "events": {
            "type": "mouseup"
          },
          "update": "main_brush ? pbiCrossFilterApply(event, \"datum['n'] > main_brush[0] & datum['n'] < main_brush[1]\" ) : pbiCrossFilterClear()"
        }
      ]
    }
    // cross filter end ------------------------------------------
  ],
  "scales": [
    {
      "name": "x_scale",
      "range": "width",
      "padding": 10,
      "domain": {
        "data": "dataset",
        "field": "n"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "y_scale",
      "range": "height",
      "padding": 10,
      "domain": {
        "data": "dataset",
        "field": "m"
      }
    }
  ],
  "axes": [
    {
      "orient": "bottom",
      "scale": "x_scale"
    },
    {
      "orient": "left",
      "scale": "y_scale"
    }
  ],
  "marks": [
    {
      "name": "main",
      "type": "group",
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "x": {
            "value": 0
          },
          "y": {
            "value": 0
          },
          "height": {
            "value": 200
          },
          "width": {
            "value": 200
          },
          "fill": {
            "value": "transparent"
          }
        }
      },
      "marks": [
        // main line chart
        {
          "name": "main_line",
          "type": "line",
          "from": {
            "data": "dataset"
          },
          "encode": {
            "enter": {
              "x": {
                "scale": "x_scale",
                "field": "n"
              },
              "y": {
                "scale": "y_scale",
                "field": "m"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        // brush area mark
        {
          "type": "rect",
          "name": "brush",
          "encode": {
            "enter": {
              "y": {
                "value": 0
              },
              "height": {
                "value": 200
              },
              "fill": {
                "value": "#333"
              },
              "fillOpacity": {
                "value": 0.2
              }
            },
            "update": {
              "x": {
                "signal": "brush[0]"
              },
              "x2": {
                "signal": "brush[1]"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

